# Spring REST custom deserialisation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is it possible to have configure spring to deserialise an incoming json how you want.

So example

```
{ "user":"abc" }
```

I would like this to hit my custom deserialiser before being processed by my by controller method.

How can i do this? I have access to an user object, but that object cannot be annotated as its external to my project.

But i would still like to populate that object and pass it into by REST method.

Comment: i think this would do it  https://dzone.com/articles/customizing

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the `objectMapper` bean implementation which contains a mixIn as:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(MyObject.class, MyObjectMixin.class);
    return mapper;
}
```

Then the mixing will be like that:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjectDeserializer.class)
public class MyObjectMixin {

}
```

And finally, the deserializer must just extends `JsonDeserializer` with the method:

```
@Override
public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
```

Comment: thanks but this wont work, as the MYObject class has no constrcutior, its a builder class.

Comment: im trying to convert a json into protobuff... hence i was trying to use mixin to do that.